# loopback format result in afterRemote hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have two models Book.json and Department.json. When I fetch book details, we are also fetching corresponding department through relation.
Output is :

```
[{
"title": "Python",
"department": {
    "name": "Software"
}
},
{
"title": "World",
"department": {
    "name": "Politics"
}
}]
```

How we can format the above code to

```
[{
"title": "Python",
"department": "Software"
},
{
"title": "World",
"department": "Politics"
}]
```

When I tried to format the **ctx.result** , it gives me an error like only getter is supported.

> "message": "Cannot set property books of #ModelConstructor which has only a getter",

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop through the items and modify each item in the iteration:

```js
const data = [{"title":"Python","department":{"name":"Software"}},{"title":"World","department":{"name":"Politics"}}];

const result = data.map(item => {
  item.department = item.department.name;
  return item;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this is not just a format issue. In the afterRemote hook of loopback, ctx.result is not a JSON output. It is an Object of ModelConstructor and simple map is not enough.

Comment: I am looking for a loopback format related answer @31piy